# ObservableCollection does not update => DataGrid UI does not show everything

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a problem with some code i wrote.
I am trying to build a Applicant-Administration program.
I have a SQL-Server on which is my Database.

At the start of the program, a DataGrid is bound to a ObservableCollection
which fires a SQL SELECT via Dapper.

If I insert a new Applicant with another SQL query, the DataGrid does not show this new Applicant.

I debugged through my program to see whats going wrong.
I think it is the ObservableCollection on which I bind.

Code of DataGrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DgInformation" ItemsSource="{Binding AllData,Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedApplicantModel, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  Grid.Row="2"
                  MaxHeight="870"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  Margin="10,5,10,5"
                  Background="#F5F5F5"
                  AlternatingRowBackground="#eeeeee" AlternationCount="2">
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="DG_Information_MouseDoubleClick" />
                    <EventSetter Event="KeyDown" Handler="DG_Information_KeyDown" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn Header="Vorname" Width="110"
                                                           EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnPopupEditingStyle}"
                                                           Binding="{Binding FirstName,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn Header="Nachname" Width="110"
                                                           EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnPopupEditingStyle}"
                                                           Binding="{Binding LastName,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn Header="Geburtstag" Width="110"
                                                           EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnPopupEditingStyle}"
                                                           Binding="{Binding Birthday,Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=\{0:dd.MM.yy\}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn Header="Schulabschluss" Width="140"
                                                           EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnPopupEditingStyle}"
                                                           Binding="{Binding Graduation.Graduation,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn Header="PLZ" Width="90"
                                                           EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnPopupEditingStyle}"
                                                           Binding="{Binding PostCode,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn Header="Ort"
                                                           EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnPopupEditingStyle}"
                                                           Binding="{Binding Address.HomePlace, Mode =TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn Header="Geschlecht"
                                                           EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnPopupEditingStyle}"
                                                           Binding="{Binding Gender.Gender,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="E-Mail"
                                         EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnPopupEditingStyle}"
                                         Binding="{Binding EMail, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <EventSetter Event="Hyperlink.Click" Handler="DgHyperlinkClick" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridHyperlinkColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridHyperlinkColumn>
                <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn Header="Stelle"
                                                           EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnPopupEditingStyle}"
                                                           Binding="{Binding Job,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                <materialDesign:MaterialDataGridTextColumn Header="Bewertung"
                                                           EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource MaterialDesignDataGridTextColumnPopupEditingStyle}"
                                                           Binding="{Binding Grade.Grade, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

My ViewModel

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private ObservableCollection<ApplicantModel> _allData;

        public BaseViewModel()
        {
            AllData = ApplicantService.GetInstance().GetAll();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ApplicantModel> AllData
        {
            get { return _allData; }
            set
            {
                _allData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

My Service Class

```
private readonly IApplicantRepository _repository;

        public ApplicantService()
        {
            _repository = new ApplicantRepository();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ApplicantModel> GetAll()
        {
            return _repository.GetAll();
        }
```

And my Repository

```
public ObservableCollection<ApplicantModel> GetAll()
        {
                var result =
                    Db.Query<ApplicantModel, AddressModel, GraduationModel, GenderModel, GradeModel, ApplicantModel>(
                        "SELECT a.ID, a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Birthday, a.EMail, a.Job, ad.PostCode, ad.HomePlace, g.Graduation, g.ID, ge.Gender, ge.ID, Grade.Grade FROM dbo.Applicant As a INNER JOIN Address As ad ON ad.PostCode = a.PostCode INNER JOIN Graduation As g ON g.ID = a.GraduationID INNER JOIN Gender As ge On ge.ID = a.GenderID INNER JOIN Grade ON Grade.Grade = a.GradeID",
                        _mapSelectGetAll, splitOn: "HomePlace,Graduation,Gender,Grade");
                Logger.LogInfo("Function GetAll executed in ApplicantRepository!");

                ObservableCollection<ApplicantModel> obsCollection = new ObservableCollection<ApplicantModel>(result);
                return obsCollection;
        }

        private ApplicantModel _mapSelectGetAll(ApplicantModel applicant, AddressModel address, GraduationModel graduation, GenderModel gender, GradeModel grade)
        {
            applicant.Graduation = graduation;
            applicant.Address = address;
            applicant.Gender = gender;
            applicant.Grade = grade;

            return applicant;
        }
```

I hope anyone can show me, where the mistake is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis is spot on :) It is indeed a problem with your binding to `AllData`, mainly because you allow it to be reassigned in a setter.

Your `DataGrid` is really only listening to the changes of your `ObservableCollection` (or rather, handling the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface. It doesn't know that your parent object has changed the collection itself (even though you fire a `PropertyChanged` event)

Ideally, you should auto-initialize observable collections, and not allow any outside setting of it. Let it handle addition/removal/resetting through the `CollectionChanged`.

The good thing is that you could now write your program in an easier way (no need to pass around `ObservableCollection<T>`)

So your viewmodel property would go to:

```
public IList<ApplicantModel> AllData { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ApplicationModel>();
```

because `ObservableCollection<T>` inherits from `IList<T>` there is no problem in dumming it down. The `DataGrid` will still detect the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface.

This does mean however that you can no longer assign a new collection to the property, but that's in essence a good thing :) Also, the `AllData` property will never be null, so that's another good thing.

However, you now need to rewrite the logic of updating your `AllData` property on your `ViewModel`

So, in case you still want to auto-fill it in the constructor, you can change the viewmodel property and constructor to:

```
public BaseViewModel() {
    AllData = new ObservableCollection<ApplicantModel>( ApplicantService.GetInstance().GetAll() );
} 

public IList<ApplicantModel> AllData { get; }
```

And no need for the private backing field, you now have a readonly auto-property instead, and the constructor utilizes the [`IEnumerable<T>` constructor parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_ObjectModel_ObservableCollection_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__) for the `ObservableCollection<T>`

Then, you should change your service class, there is really no reason for it to return a full blown `ObservableCollection<ApplicantModel>()`, just let it return `IEnumerable<ApplicantModel>` or at most a `IReadOnlyList<ApplicantModel>`.

This change then also needs to go to your `Repository`.

This then eventually leaves you to handle deletions and updates of data. If you are working with some local database, just acting upon save/delete requests would be fine, if you work with a central database, it might be more involving :)

Hopefully it's not to much text :)

Comment: Hi Icepickle, I should have said, that I have two ViewModels, Base- and MainViewModel. MainViewModel inherits BaseViewModel. I tried to use your code. I changed the constructor an the property of my BaseViewModel and changed the thing in my service class and repository. When I try to compile now, i get an "System.InvalidOperationException": "TwoWay or OneWayToSource bindings do not work with the read-only property "AllData" of type "Applicant ManagementCSharp.ViewModels.MainViewModel". What schould I do now? I havent seen this exception before

Comment: Ah, if i set it to BindMode OneWay, it compiles, but the DataGrid does not refresh its ItemsSource after insert

Comment: @NoahAnleitner Right, that's completely correct, if you have 2 way, it would assume that you would be updating `AllData` as well, but that shouldn't be the case. So what kind of insert are you doing, and how are you updating the `AllData` then?

Answer (score 0):

@Icepickle

My Insert query is:

```
public void CreateApplicant(ApplicantModel applicant, AddressModel address, GraduationModel graduation, GenderModel gender, GradeModel grade)
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO Applicant(FirstName,LastName,PostCode,Birthday,GenderID,Email,Job,GraduationID,GradeID)" + "Values(@FirstName,@LastName,@PostCode,@Birthday,@Gender,@Email,@Job,@Graduation,@Grade)";

            try
            {
                Db.Execute(query, new
                {
                    FirstName = applicant.FirstName,
                    LastName = applicant.LastName,
                    Birthday = applicant.Birthday,
                    PostCode = applicant.PostCode,
                    Graduation = graduation.ID,
                    Gender = gender.ID,
                    Email = applicant.EMail,
                    Job = applicant.Job,
                    Grade = grade.Grade,
                });
                Logger.LogInfo("Function AddApplicant executed in ApplicantRepository!");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

And the different details are filled into textboxes which are bound to the properties of my database